# Spring: Implement a share-via-link feature for web application

Tags: java, spring, angular, rest, spring-boot

I have a requirement where I need to implement a `share-application-state-via-link` feature.

My application is a video streaming single page application consisting of some dropdown options for user to filter out available videos and a video player to play the selected videos.

Now first on the basis of dropdown options , a user selects the available videos and add it to video player. At max 4 videos could be added. Now after that, I need to share this state of my application to some other user so I get a share link(just like Share answer in StackOverflow) and I send this to other user. This other user just need to hit this URL and it will load the exact state of application with videos added to player and dropdown populated with respective options.

**My Approach:**

I have a `/getVideo` `rest service` which fetches the video data and send it as `json` response back to `angular` based frontend. I have created a `Share` button which when clicked, creates a link by adding all the selected dropdown options something like: 
`https://localhost:8080/MyApp/shared?genre=Action&type=web-series`

I have created a method `/shared` which will take these params and call the `/getVideo` internally.

The problem here is, I need to load `index.html` when the above link is hit. I also have to send the getVideo data to be loaded with `index.html` and the application should function properly. Am not able to solve this problem and need help.

Is my approach correct? Is there any alternate way? Am using `Spring-Boot` for backend and `angular2` for frontend.

Here is the `/shared` API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/shared", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  String getSharedVideo(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, 
        @RequestParam(value="genre", required=false) String genre,
        @RequestParam(value="date", required=false) String date,
        @RequestParam(value="type", required=false) String type,
        @RequestParam(value="version", required=false) String version,
        @RequestParam(value="category", required=false) String category
        ){
    List<Lab> lab = null;
    try {
        lab = videoService.getVideo(genre, date, type, version, category);
        redirectAttributes.addAllAttributes(lab); // how to send this data to frontend
        return "index.html";

    } catch(Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("EXCEPTION - " + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151202/spring-boot-implement-a-share-feature-for-web-application) over and over...

Comment: Are there any rules for that?